# Joining multiple tables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on healthcare data. For the sake of simplicity, I am providing data on only one patient ID. Every patient has a unique ID and over a period of time, the doctors monitor the BCR_ABL value as shown in the table below.

```
structure(list(PatientId = c("Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124", 
"Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124", 
"Hospital1_124"), TestDate = c("2007-11-13", "2008-09-01", "2011-02-24", 
"2013-05-01", "2016-02-16", "2017-05-12", "2017-08-29"), BCR_ABL = c(0.029, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .Names = c("PatientId", "TestDate", 
"BCR_ABL"))
```

At the start of the treatment, each patient has a BCR_ABL value of 100 and ideally post treatment, this value should drop down to 0. The patients undergo tests for BCR_ABL at various stages as shown in the `TestDate` column.

The patients also visit the hospital for follow up visits and this is recorded in another table which contains the followup date as well as the date of starting of the medication. The table looks like this:

```
structure(list(PatientId = c("Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124", 
"Hospital1_124", "Hospital1_124"), FollowupDate = structure(c(11323, 
17298, 17407, 17553), class = "Date"), dateofStarting = structure(c(11323, 
17318, 17318, 17318), class = "Date"), nameTKI = c("Imatinib", 
"Imatinib", "Imatinib", "Imatinib"), brandTKI = c("Glivec", "Glivec", 
"Glivec", "Glivec"), dailydose = c("100", "400", "400", "400"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0>, .Names = c("PatientId", 
"FollowupDate", "dateofStarting", "nameTKI", "brandTKI", "dailydose"
))
```

Now the aim of the analysis is to find out the efficacy of the drug (`nameTKI`) being prescribed. To my mind, the best representation would be a line graph with `Date` on the x-axis and `BCR_ABL` on the y-axis. However, I am stuck on how do I go about combining the dates. I am looking at a new table which has the following variables: `PatientId`, `Date`, `BCR_ABL`, `nameTKI`, `brandTKI` and `dailydose`. I don't think the follow up date has too much of a significance. So negelecting it, the `Date` variable needs to be a combination of `TestDate` from the first table and `dateofStarting` from the second table, arranged chronologically for all the individual patients (I could use `group_by()` for that). The value for `BCR_ABL` would start off as 100, till the value obtained after the first test and then follow those values for all the `Date` entries.

I have been trying various `join`s from `dplyr` without any success. Would appreciate some help please.

Comment: You could look into [aggregate](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html)

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to follow your code there, but you could join the tables together using the PatientId as the primary key.  However, you should think carefully about the structure of the data as well.  If the first table is at the patient/test level and the second is supposed to just be at the patient level; why are there multiple dateofStarting values for a single PatientId?

```
library(tidyverse)

t1 <- data.frame(PatientId = rep("Hospital1_124", 7),
                 TestDate = as.Date(c("2007-11-13", "2008-09-01", "2011-02-24", "2013-05-01", 
                                      "2016-02-16", "2017-05-12", "2017-08-29")), 
                 BCR_ABL = c(0.029, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



t2 <- data.frame(PatientId = rep("Hospital1_124", 4),
                 FollowupDate = as.Date(c(11323, 17298, 17407, 17553), origin = "1970-01-01"),
                 dateofStarting = as.Date(c(11323, 17318, 17318, 17318), origin = "1970-01-01"),
                 nameTKI = rep("Imatinib", 4),
                 brandTKI = rep("Glivec", 4),
                 dailydose = c(100, 400, 400, 400),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


data <- t2 %>% 
  select(-FollowupDate) %>% 
  inner_join(t1, by = c("PatientId" = "PatientId"))
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. As I explained above, patients come for follow up visits and it is during these visits that the dosage or brand of the medicine might change. The date from which the new dosage is to be started is recorded under `dateofStarting`. The `inner_join()` doesn't quite solve this. I am looking at a single concatenated `Date` variable which is a combination of `TestDate` and `dateofStarting` arranged chronologically for every `PatientId`. Thanks